# Programmatically set the default layout in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I'm working on Liferay 6.1 bundled with Tomcat 7.0. I've created my own layout using the liferay plugin. It looks like:

```
<div class="MyLayout" id="main-content" role="main">
<div class="portlet-layout">
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-1">
        $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portlet-layout">
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only" id="column-2">
        $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portlet-layout">
    <div class="aui-w25 portlet-column portlet-column-first" id="column-3">
        $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-first")
    </div>
    <div class="aui-w75 portlet-column portlet-column-last" id="column-4">
        $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-last")
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to programmatically set this layout as default layout for all pages. How can I achieve this ? Any valuable suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default layout by configuration of liferay. Create a `portal-ext.properties` in the `bundles`-folder and put this two properties for default layout:

```
layout.default.template.id = MyLayout
default.layout.template.id = MyLayout
```

You must set both properties, else the portal throws exception by startup.

PS: Ask me, if this solution isn't for you, and you want realy to set the layout programmaticaly.

Comment: Hi Mark, when i set these properties and created a new page, some warnings like below are shown: WARN  [ThemeLocalServiceImpl:149] No theme found for specified theme id . Returning the default theme.

Comment: That is ok, because at start of portal, Liferay redeploy the theme. At begin the themeis not available, but after starting is finished the theme is available. So after start you should get no warnings.

Comment: Still i'm getting warning even after server startup.

Comment: Do you have changed the theme config. You quastion was about default layout, not default theme?

Comment: No I didn't changed the theme config.The default layout is still 2 column layout in the 'Page layout' option even after setting these properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the code in the seven-cogs-hook which comes bundled with liferay.